# How to find a 5-edge colouring of the cartesian product $P$ (peterson graph) $\Box$ $K_{3}$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The cartesian product of $P \Box K_3$ looks like three Peterson graphs, with vertices labeled 1a,..,10a, 1b,..,10b, 1c,...,10c. Where each Peterson graph a, b or c, has ten vertices 1 until 10. The vertices 1a, 1b, 1c are connected as well, 2a, 2b, 2c are connected, and so on.

I want to find a specific 5-edge colouring for this graph and a good starting point seems to be a 'relabeling': I have drawn ten vertices labeled by the ten numbers of $\binom{5}{3}$ and connected them if there was only one number in common (e.g. 123 was connected with 345, 245 and 145). Each number 1 until 5 represents a colour.

I don't know how to colour the other two Peterson graphs s.t. $P\Box K_3$ has a 5-edge colouring. I only know that there two colours which we see at the edges adjacent to 1a, 1b and 1c. (referring to the first representation)

Can someone help me?

Comment: we need to loke for $5$ edge disjoint matchings

Comment: If we wish to use the full strength of the relabeling then we should ‘simultaneously’ label each copy of the Petersen graph $P$, right? It seems that for this purpose we should find two isomorphisms $\varphi$  and $\psi$  of $P$ such that for each vertex $\{i,j,k\}$ we have $|\{i,j,k\}\cup \varphi(\{i,j,k\})|=4$, $|\psi(\{i,j,k\})\cup \varphi(\{i,j,k\})|=4$, and $|\{i,j,k\}\cup \psi(\{i,j,k\})|=4$. But maybe we can quicker find the coloring of the graph $P \Box K_3$  by tries and errors.